# How to calculate computational complexity of these methods/algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I'm doing an universitary project about k-ary tree implementation in Java and now I need to calculate the computational complexity (worst case) of some methods (or algorithms) that I previously implemented.

At the end of every method I wrote what I think the computational complexity of the method should be.

```
int ar; //arity of tree, given by user
List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>(ar);

public void addChild(Node<T> n) {
    if(this.numberOfChildren()>=ar){
        System.out.println("Impossible to add: "+n.getInfo());
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i<ar; i++){
            if(this.children.get(i)==null){
                n.setParent(this);
                this.children.set(i,n);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Computational complexity: O(n).

```
public int numberOfChildren() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<ar; i++){
        if(this.children.get(i)!=null){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Computational complexity: O(n).

```
public LinkedList<T> visitDFSA() {
    LinkedList<T> nodiVisita=new LinkedList<T>();
    LinkedList<Node<T>> stack=new LinkedList<Nodo_m_ario<T>>();
    stack.addFirst(this.root);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        Nodo_m_ario<T> u=stack.removeFirst();
        if(u!=null){
            nodiVisita.addLast(u.getInfo());
            for(int i=Node.ar-1;i>=0;i--){
                stack.addFirst((u.childrenList().get(i)));
            }
        }
    }
    return nodiVisita;
}
```

Computational complexity: O(n²).

```
public LinkedList<T> simmetricVisit(Node<T> node) {
    if (node==null){

    }else{
        for (int i=0;i<Node.ar/2;i++){
            simmetricVisit(node.children.get(i));
        }
        vs.add(nodo.getInfo());
        for (int i=Node.ar/2;i<Node.ar;i++){
            simmetricVisit(node.children.get(i));
        }
    }
    return vs;
}
```

Computational complexity: O(n).

```
public void graft(Node<T> u, Tree<T> subTree) {
    if(u==null){
        System.out.println("Can't add the subtree to node u.");
    }else{
        Node<T> rootSubTree = subTree.getRoot();
        rootSubTree.parent = u;
        u.addChild(rootSubTree);
    }
}
```

Computational complexity: O(1).

Is there something wrong in what I wrote (talking about computational complexity values)?
I think so.
So I think i might need some help... :(

Comment: Voting to close because it's not a question, it's ton of questions.

Comment: @amit I reduced the number of questions.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to validate your conclusions.  Take `numberOfChildren()`, for example: it invokes `this.children.get(i)` in its loop, so its complexity depends on the complexity of that method, which we cannot determine.

Comment: Additionally, many of the methods presented depend on variables whose nature and range of values are not given.  Variable `ar` features in several, for instance.  If `ar`'s value is bounded by a constant, then that affects the complexity of these methods.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, children is an ArrayList of ar size. ar is the arity of the tree. So the get method is of ArrayList class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Methods `void addChild(Node<T> n)` and `int numberOfChildren()`

Each of these methods performs up to `ar` iterations of a single loop.  Supposing that the operations performed in these loops (variously `numberOfChildren()`, `Node.setParent()`, and `Node.getInfo()`) are `O(1)`, these methods are `O(ar)`, which is `O(1)` unless you're doing really weird things with arity.  Alternatively, for any given `ar` *taken as a constant*, these methods are definitely `O(1)`, regardless of the actual value chosen for `ar`.

### Methods `LinkedList<T> visitDFSA()` and `LinkedList<T> simmetricVisit(Node<T> node)`

These are a little less obvious, but it appears that each method visits each node exactly once, at a cost of `O(ar)` per visit.  That makes both of these methods `O(n * ar)` overall for `n` total nodes.  That becomes as good as `O(n)` if `ar` is taken to itself be `O(1)`, **or** if tree height is guaranteed to be the minimum possible.  It would also be `O(n)` if the methods didn't have to deal with `null` children, instead processing only the real children.

### Method void graft(Node u, Tree subTree)

Supposing that `Node.addChild()` and `Tree.getRoot()` are each `O(1)`, a fixed maximum number of the operations is performed.  That's `O(1)`.

Comment: thank you so much for your exhaustive answer, I really appreciate it :)